# $f$ is differentiable iff there exists a constant and a function such that...

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

In [these lecture notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/intro_analysis_pdf/intro_analysis.html), there is the following proposition (chapter 8, proposition 8.11):

> **Proposition.** Suppose that $f: (a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $c\in (a,b)$ if and only if there exists a constant $A\in\mathbb{R}$ and a function $r: (a-c,b-c)\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(c+h)=f(c)+Ah+r(h), \quad \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{r(h)}{h}=0.$$ In that case, $A=f'(c)$.

Why is $r$ a function from $(a-c,b-c)$?

Comment: what do you propose instead?

Comment: Note that we must have the condition $a<c+h<b$.

Comment: Yes, it's clear now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r(h):=f(c+h)-f(c)-Ah$ to be defined, $c+h$ must belong to $(a,b).$